# T-SQL : why is running multiple sql statements in one batch slower without GO?

Tags: performance, t-sql

I have come to very interesting problem (at least for me).

When I run following SQL:

```
SELECT count(*) AS [count]
FROM [dbo].[contract_v] AS [contract_v]
WHERE 1 = 0;

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[contract] AS [contract]
LEFT JOIN ([dbo].[contract_accepted_garbage_type] AS [garbageTypes->contract_accepted_garbage_type]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[garbage_type] AS [garbageTypes] ON [garbageTypes].[id] = [garbageTypes->contract_accepted_garbage_type].[garbage_type_id]) 
     ON [contract].[id] = [garbageTypes->contract_accepted_garbage_type].[contract_id]
WHERE [contract].[id] IN (125018);
```

Execution takes 21s

However when I add GO statement as following:

```
SELECT count(*) AS [count]
FROM [dbo].[contract_v] AS [contract_v]
WHERE 1 = 0;

GO

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[contract] AS [contract]
LEFT JOIN ([dbo].[contract_accepted_garbage_type] AS [garbageTypes->contract_accepted_garbage_type]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[garbage_type] AS [garbageTypes] ON [garbageTypes].[id] = [garbageTypes->contract_accepted_garbage_type].[garbage_type_id])
     ON [contract].[id] = [garbageTypes->contract_accepted_garbage_type].[contract_id]
WHERE [contract].[id] IN (125018);
```

It takes only 2s.

The view used in first SQL statement is based on the table called in second statement.

Could you please explain this behaviour to me? I know that GO statement makes database create separate execution plan for every batch. I have checked the execution plans, and the actual steps are identical.

Thank you!

Comment: `GO` is **not** a SQL statement - it's a **delimiter** used by e.g. SQL Server Mgmt Studio (and tools like `sqlcmd`) to separate **batches** of SQL statements.

Comment: What did you do between trials to flush caches, ...? Did you try running the `GO`/no `GO` examples in the reverse order? A common issue when benchmarking performance is that the first operation loads tables, indexes, ... into memory and it is still there when the second query runs, thus saving on physical reads.

Comment: @HABO I have tried this in various combination, every time the case without GO are slower, when I run the statement without GO multiple times, every time it takes 20s. It seems that DB cache has nothing to do with this performance issue.

Answer (score 2):

The GO keyword separates execution batches.  If the underlying tables are the same in both queries, and they are executed in the same batch, both queries have to be executed with the same transaction context.  This ensures that the underlying data in both tables is the same during both executions.

If using separate batches (GO statement in-between), you cannot guarantee that the data will be consistent in that rows could theoretically be modified in between executions.

If you don't care about the chance of the data changing in between queries, then by all means use GO for performance.  If you do care, consider it a dangerous move.

> SQL Server applications can send multiple Transact-SQL statements to an instance of SQL Server for execution as a batch. The statements in the batch are then **compiled into a single execution plan**. Programmers executing ad hoc statements in the SQL Server utilities, or building scripts of Transact-SQL statements to run through the SQL Server utilities, use GO to signal the end of a batch.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I understand that GO separates executions into batches, but why is there so significant performance difference, mainly if the execution plans that query tables are identical.

Comment: If contract_v is looking at the same records as the second query, then it may be attempting to lock the records to make sure that the data is consistent for both queries within the same batch, since it's doing a count. It's possible that the optimizer isn't checking the 1=0 until it's too late, ex table scan.  Why do you have that always false 1=0 anyway?